# meaning of 'the guts of the fountain'

Tags: meaning-in-context

> The bronze idol, her hair pinned up with a crescent-moon tiara,
>   gripped two massive torches, one in each hand, their flames rising
>   past the level of her shoulders. A skeleton key dangled between her
>   bare breasts. At her feet was a basket of hissing snakes, copper
>   tubing in their coils feeding down into the 'guts' of the fountain.

This is from the description of a fountain in the atrium. I'm not sure about the meaning of the 'gut' here. Does this mean narrow passage or inner parts of the fountain?

Comment: I'd say the inner parts: more piping, a water pump, and whatever else is in there.

Answer (score 1):

Guts: is used with the following meaning:

> the inner working parts of a machine or device:
>
> - The mechanic had the guts of the refrigerator laid out on the kitchen floor.

(Dictionary.com)